# Creating zip archive in php

Tags: php, zip

I'm trying to creat zip archives with php using this class: [Site](http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php)

**The first problem:**

in the array of `$files_to_zip`. I need to add the path of the app in all of the dates, how i do this?

Convert this array:

```
$files_to_zip = array(
'preload-images/1.jpg',
'preload-images/2.jpg',
'preload-images/5.jpg',
'kwicks/ringo.gif',
'rod.jpg',
'reddit.gif'
  );
```

To this:

```
$files_to_zip = array(
'path/to/app/preload-images/1.jpg',
'path/to/app/preload-images/2.jpg',
'path/to/app/preload-images/5.jpg',
'path/to/app/kwicks/ringo.gif',
'path/to/app/rod.jpg',
'path/to/app/reddit.gif'
  );
```

**The second problem:**

When the ZIP was created, they create every folder of the path of the archive.
Example: ZIP > folder "path" > folder "to" > folder "app" > archives.

I want just the archives in the ZIP.

I don't know where I change the code or what is wrong.
Help pls?

Comment: The second problem is because of the class you are using. It uses the path to the file as the file's name inside the zip.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the first problem solution

```
$files_to_zip = array(
'preload-images/1.jpg',
'preload-images/2.jpg',
'preload-images/5.jpg',
'kwicks/ringo.gif',
'rod.jpg',
'reddit.gif'
 );

$dir = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/test/'; 
$new_files = array();
  foreach($files_to_zip as $value){
   $new_files[] = $dir.$value;
}
print_r($new_files);
```

For second problem, you can use [PCLZIP](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/) .

```
require_once('pclzip.lib.php');
// Create Object
$archive = new PclZip("compressed.zip");
/*
$compress = $archive->add($p_filelist, $p_option, $p_option_value, ...);

$files_archive = $archive->add($new_files, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_PATH, $dir, PCLZIP_OPT_ADD_PATH, 'myFiles');
Here, 
$new_files = Array of files
PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_PATH = http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/user-guide/29
PCLZIP_OPT_ADD_PATH = http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/user-guide/28
*/
$files_archive = $archive->add($new_files, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_PATH, $dir, PCLZIP_OPT_ADD_PATH, 'myFiles');
if ($files_archive == 0) {
    die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
}   
else{
    echo "Archive Created";
}
```

So, overall you code will look like this:

```
<?php
require_once('pclzip.lib.php');
$files_to_zip = array(
'preload-images/1.jpg',
'preload-images/2.jpg',
'preload-images/5.jpg',
'kwicks/ringo.gif',
'rod.jpg',
'reddit.gif'
 );

$dir = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/test/'; 
$new_files = array();
  foreach($files_to_zip as $value){
   $new_files[] = $dir.$value;
}
print_r($new_files);
// Create Object
$archive = new PclZip("compressed.zip");
/*
$compress = $archive->add($p_filelist, $p_option, $p_option_value, ...);

$files_archive = $archive->add($new_files, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_PATH, $dir, PCLZIP_OPT_ADD_PATH, 'myFiles');
Here, 
$new_files = Array of files
PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_PATH = http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/user-guide/29
PCLZIP_OPT_ADD_PATH = http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/user-guide/28
*/
$files_archive = $archive->add($new_files, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_PATH, $dir, PCLZIP_OPT_ADD_PATH, 'myFiles');
if ($files_archive == 0) {
    die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
}   
else{
    echo "Archive Created";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The first solution is perfect. The second, I removed the total path of the name of file in the zip class, using str_replace. (see the comment in the question).

Answer (score 1):

first problem solution

```
foreach($files_to_zip as &$value){
   $value = 'path/to/app/'.$value
}
```

or use array_walk

second problem:

try to create tmp folder, copy every file to it and zip em.
This is simpliest solution.
Don't forget to remove tmp files.